# Is there a simple way to install the pkg-tool noninteractively

Tags: freebsd

I'm fairly new to FreeBSD.
I write a script to automate unattended installation.
I understand that right tool for this job is `bsdinstall`

Right now I write the setup-script for `bsdinstall`.

I test this script standalone, not with `bsdinstall`.

Since `pkg` is not installed yet, it wants interactive confirmation to bootstrap itself.
Can I get rid of this interactive confirmation easily?
I want to avoid `expect`, because I think there must be an easier way.

my attempts sofar:

```
pkg bootstrap
pkg bootstrap -f
yes | pkg bootstrap
yes | pkg bootstrap -f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set `ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES` variable to `yes`.

```
set ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES = yes
pkg bootstrap
```

This information written by `pkg` when invoke `yes | pkg bootstrap -f`:

> Please set ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=yes environment variable to be able to
>   bootstrap in non-interactive (stdin not being a tty)

Comment: the notice was never written to the console in my case. ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES works for me, I had to write it like this, though:
env ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=YES pkg bootstrap

Comment: The command may depends on your shell.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same trouble with a brand new jail

the solution:

1- create directory: /usr/local/etc

2- create file: /usr/local/etc/pkg.conf with:

```
DEFAULT_ALWAYS_YES = true;
ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES = true;
```

and run:

```
ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=yes pkg bootstrap -yf
```

it should be ok